# Remove .htaccess 301 RedirectMatch trailing slash?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a redirectMatch rule in place:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /dir/subdir/safety-program(.*) /dir/subdir/safety-program/$1
```

When I load the safety-program address, like so:

```
http://localhost/dir/subdir/saftey-program/
```

or

```
http://localhost/dir/subdir/saftey-program
```

I get the safety-program page returned with the following address, with an extra trailing slash:

```
http://localhost/dir/subdir/safety-program//
```

Why is the match adding that second slash? How do I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here `safety-program/$1` and it should be like this `safety-program$1`

> why you should change it

the RedirectMatch comes like this

```
RedirectMatch [status] regex URL
```

So the `[status]` is: `301` and `regex` is :  `/dir/subdir/safety-program(.*)` then there is a `url` which is : `/dir/subdir/safety-program/$1` and this part, `$1`, of `url` will match this part ,`(.*)`, of `regex` , so you put slash in this `(.*)` then it comes to `url` like this `$1` including that slash , and you expressed about it like this `/$1` in `url` , so that why double slash occurred.

That what you did exactly.

Whenever request `/dir/subdir/safety-program/` it would be  `/dir/subdir/safety-program//`

so change the line code to be :

```
RedirectMatch 301 /dir/subdir/safety-program(.*) /dir/subdir/safety-program$1
```

OR this  :

```
RedirectMatch 301 /dir/subdir/safety-program/(.*) /dir/subdir/safety-program/$1
```